# Is there a way of working in spherical coordinates in SymPy?

Tags: python, vector, sympy, spherical-coordinate

I am working in a script to do analytical calculations in Python. For it I would need vector representation of my parameters and also some basic vector operations such as Gradient and Divergence, and for this reason I started working in SymPy. However, I noticed there is not a straightforward way of working in spherical coordinates.

After reading the documentation I found out a Cartessian environment can be simply defined as

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

N = CoordSys3D('N')
```

and directly start working with the unitary cartessian unitary vectors i, j, k

```
v = 2*N.i + 3*N.j - N.k
```

Is there any way of initializing such an environment for spherical coordinates where I have access to radial, theta and phi unitary vectors, and consequently the basic  vector operations are done accordingly?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access spherical coordinate unitary vectors as 'r', 't', 'p' (or you can use full names like 'radius', 'theta', 'phi') instead of 'i', 'j', ,'k' if you indicate that the transformation is 'spherical':

```
>>> from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
>>> P = CoordSys3D('P', transformation='spherical', variable_names=list('rtp'))
>>> P.r
P.r
```

Comment: That is great! But still, basic operations in this coordinate description don't seem to work the way they should. A simple example, I would expect
`P.r * P.t = P.p`
However, that is not the case. And how do I have access to the parameters "radius", "theta" and "phi" themselves, not simply the uinitary vectors...?

Comment: A good place to start reading is the CoordSys3D docstring and then the test file for that function. I'm afraid we are close to on the same page and I wouldn't have too much to add. There is also the diffgeom module that may be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

After some reading I found out one can define the variables of the new base with
`variable_names()`
and the unitary vectors of the new base as
`vector_names()`

So the complete definition of a spherical coordinate system would be

```
P = CoordSys3D('P', transformation='spherical',
                    vector_names=list('rtp'), 
                    variable_names=list('RTP'))
```

Now the unitary vectors do respect the proper relations, e.g

```
P.r & P.t = 0
P.r ^ P.t = P.p
```

where `&` stands for dot product and `^` for cross product

Answer (score 1):

Seems spherical transformation is not fully implemented.

I tried to transform a spherical CoordSys3D to cartesian but I don't get it to work as expected.

Simpy provides the function "express" but it seems just to work on tilted Systems not on spherical coordinates.

```
>>> from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, express
>>> N = CoordSys3D('N')
>>> from sympy.abc import a
>>> M = N.orient_new_axis('M', a, N.k)
>>> v1 = 1*N.i + 1*N.j + 1*N.k
>>> express(v1, M)
(sin(a) + cos(a))*M.i + (-sin(a) + cos(a))*M.j + M.k
>>> O = N.create_new('O', transformation='spherical')
>>> express(v1, O)
O.i + O.j + O.k
```

I expect the output in the last line to contain spherical variables ('rtp') from O and also some more floating numbers from trigonometric calculations.

Am I missing something?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34691466)

Comment: I was also confused about how to do this in a built-in way - but I think I was able to use the Jacobian to transform more general coordinates: 

`import sympy as sp; \n
from sympy import vector`

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689096/2561747) I was also confused about how to do spherical coordinate transformations in a built-in way - but I think I was able to use the Jacobian to transform more general coordinates:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import vector

cart = vector.CoordSys3D('cart')
sph = cart.create_new('sph', transformation='spherical', vector_names=list('RTP'))
trans = sp.Matrix(sph.transformation_to_parent())

x, y, z = sp.symbols('x, y, z')
v = sp.Matrix([x, y, z]) # arbitrary expression: x*i + y*j + z*k

J = trans.jacobian([sph.r, sph.theta, sph.phi])

new_expr = v.subs([(x, trans[0]), (y, trans[1]), (z, trans[2])])
vp = J.transpose() @ new_expr
[_.simplify() for _ in vp]
# out: [sph.r, 0, 0]
```