# How do I work with vectors in cylindrical and spherical systems with SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

With SymPy, I can perform basic mathematical operations with vectors in cartesian system. For example:

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

N = CoordSys3D('N')

v1 = 3*N.i - 2*N.j - 4*N.k # Vector 1
v2 = 2*N.i - 4*N.j + 2*N.k # Vector 2

print(v1 + v2) # Sum
print(v1 - v2) # Difference
print(v1 & v2) # Dot product
print(v1 ^ v2) # Cross product
print(v1.magnitude()) # Magnitude
print(v1.normalize()) # Normalize
```

But when I try to do the same in another coordinate system. For example, lets calculate the magnitude of a vector in cylindrical system:

```
from sympy import pi
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

N = CoordSys3D('N', transformation='cylindrical', variable_names=("rho", "phi", "z"))

v1 = 4*N.i + (pi/2)*N.j + 3*N.k

print(v1.magnitude())
```

The output is `sqrt(pi**2/4 + 25)` but the spected is `5`.

What is the correct way to perform all these operations with vectors in different coordinate systems?

Comment: Very related, possible duplicate: [python - Is there a way of working in spherical coordinates in SymPy? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61100589/is-there-a-way-of-working-in-spherical-coordinates-in-sympy)

Comment: It looks like that you would have to convert them to Cartesian coordinate before taking the magnitude...?

Comment: Perhaps, but mathematically this can be done by making the dot product of the vector in cylindrical coordinates with each of the unit vectors of the Cartesian coordinate system, but I have just verified that this operation does not perform well either. It seems that with SymPy it is not as simple as it seems.

Comment: There is some discussion about this with an example of converting between systems [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sympy/c/Bk78RKPcQ8c/m/GXY58Gs_DAAJ)